# Angular ngRoute not working parameters

Tags: angularjs

Guys I got a problem (lack of experience) in ngRouter, I can work with the parameters in routes with two ex levels:

> editoria/:itemId

```
.when('/editoria/:itemId',{
        templateUrl:"templates/editoria/index.html",
        controller:'EditoriaCtrl'
})
```

however, must use a primary route

> /:editoriaId

```
.when('/:itemId',{
        templateUrl:"templates/editoria/index.html",
        controller:'EditoriaCtrl'
    })
```

I hope I have been clear, hehe

how do I do?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with `ngRoute`, you specify the path (starting from base) to match the route so you need to specify it fully.

If you were to use `ui.router` - a much more feature-rich alternative to `ngRoute` - then you could have a parent-child relationship of states:

```
.state("editoria", {
  abstract: true,
  url: "/editoria"
})
.state("editoria.item", {
  url: "/:itemId",
  templateUrl: "templates/editoria/index.html",
  controller: "EditoriaCtrl"
})
```

Comment: you're right, I am using ui-router and really has become simpler, thanks!